# Reflexive relation with nested data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm sorry if this is a basic question, but since I'm quite new to ember, I'd like to know if there is any best practice for a case like this.  For example, I have the follow endpoints that returns the payloads below:

https://api.example.com/v1/user

```
[
    {
        "user": "user1",
        "firstName": "Foo1",
        "lastName": "Bar1",
        "url": "https://api.example.com/v1/user/user1"
    },
    {
        "user": "user2",
        "firstName": "Foo2",
        "lastName": "Bar2",
        "url": "https://api.example.com/v1/user/user2"
    }
]
```

And each of the "url" endpoint returns something like this:

https://api.example.com/v1/user/user1

```
{
    "user": "user1",
    "firstName": "Foo1",
    "lastName": "Bar1",
    "age": 21,
    "address": "User1 Address"
    ... more info ...
}
```

We see that some properties in `"/user"` are repeated in `"/user/user1"`.

What would be the best practice to create the `"user"` model?

Should I have two models? Like for example a `"users"` model for the `"/user"` and a `"user"` model for `"/user/user1"`?

Could somehow have just one model `"user"` that would fit both endpoints?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: All you need is a model that has all those fields. There is no requirement on which fields need to be set or anything

Comment: There is an issue with the above, @NullVoxPopuli ... it is difficult to know when a model is fully loaded or not if you use a single model. I recommend adding a property 'isFullyLoaded' and set it to false by default, but make it true in the serializer for the single user by overriding normalizeSingleResponse method. Then in a user detail route you can check that and reload the record only if false.

Alternatively, if you use two models, you have to manage a belongsTo relationship between them or use the same id for both models and use peekRecord everywhere to get one from the other.

Comment: @Leandro Alves No worries, this is not too basic a question; this is one of the situations where there is no documented best practice. Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: @NullVoxPopuli, I thought the fields had to be set but if it's not mandatory, then using only one model with the "isFullyLoaded" flag could be an option.

Comment: @Gaurav, Regarding having two modules with belongsTo I was wondering how to solve having for example "model.user.firstName" and "model.user.url.firstName" since they are the same user.

Comment: [ember-data-partial-model](https://github.com/BookingSync/ember-data-partial-model) is addressing that issue but doesn't seem to be maintained that well. Maybe it's just overhead as @Gaurav's approach seems to do the same and model's `reload()` method should provide a way to fetch extended information.

Answer (score 1):

This is almost the use case [described in the one-to-one docs](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/models/relationships/#toc_one-to-one) where you're defining the user data with one model and linking another model with a belongsTo attribute:

```js
// app/models/user.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  user: DS.attr('string'),
  firstName: DS.attr('string'),
  lastName: DS.attr('string'),
  url: DS.attr('string'),

  profile: DS.belongsTo('profile')
});
```

then setup a profile model with any extra values you're wanting to add and define the belongsTo attribute also:

```js
// app/models/profile.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  age: DS.attr('string'),
  address: DS.attr('string'),

  user: DS.belongsTo('user')
});
```

In your routes file you'll want to setup the user id to define your URL structure like so:

```js
//app/router.js
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('users');
  this.route('user', { path: '/user/:user_id' });
});
```

Then finally you'll need to load the data [retrieving the related records](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/models/relationships/#toc_retrieving-related-records) and loading them in via your route file.

```js
// app/routes/user.js
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

export default Route.extend({
  model(params) {
   return this.store.findRecord('user', params.user_id, {include: 'profile'});
  }
});
```

It's worth pointing out that you may also [need a serializer](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/models/customizing-serializers/#toc_customizing-serializers) to massage the data into the format you're wanting.

Comment: thanks for your time answering here. How would this fit with the `findAll()` case? Each user in the array would have all its attributes? Regarding your suggestion above, would the `age` attribute be accessed in the template by `model.user.profile.age` or `model.user.age`?  When you say "massage the data", what suggestion do you have in mind that could be done? Thanks a lot!